# Recursion: Index not updating

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find pairings in the variable 'coordKeys' down to the element level.

```
coordKeys = [0,1,2,3,4]

pairingDict = {}
index = 1
def scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict, index):
    length = len(coordKeys)
    if length == 1:
        return 
    
    dividerInd = math.ceil(length/2)
    firstHalf = coordKeys[:dividerInd]
    secondHalf = coordKeys[dividerInd:]
    
    pairingDict[index] = (firstHalf, secondHalf)
    index += 1

    print(pairingDict)    
    scheduler(firstHalf, pairingDict, index)
    print(pairingDict)
    scheduler(secondHalf, pairingDict, index)
    print(pairingDict)
    return pairingDict

result = scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict, index)
print(result)
```

```
Output:
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([3], [4]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([3], [4]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([3], [4]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([3], [4]), 3: ([0], [1])}
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([3], [4]), 3: ([0], [1])}
```

What I want in the output's last line:

```
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1]), 4:([3], [4])}
```

Can't figure out why the value of 'index' variable is not staying put at 4.  Please help on why calling 'scheduler' function on the [3],[4] part is thinking that index's value is 2.

Comment: `scheduler(secondHalf, pairingDict, index)`: can you describe what this index is doing?

Comment: All the pairings will be collected in the pairingDict. 'index' is the key for that pairingDict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are immutable. When you perform `index += 1` it actually assigns to the local variable `index` a new integer object instead of mutating the original, so when the recursive calls return, the local variable `index` in the parent frame retains the reference to the original integer object, resulting your `([3], [4])` getting assigned to the key `2`, the value of `index` at that level of the recursion.

To work around it, you can either make `index` a mutable list containing an integer instead:

```
import math

coordKeys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

pairingDict = {}
index = [1]

def scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict, index):
    length = len(coordKeys)
    if length == 1:
        return

    dividerInd = math.ceil(length / 2)
    firstHalf = coordKeys[:dividerInd]
    secondHalf = coordKeys[dividerInd:]

    pairingDict[index[0]] = (firstHalf, secondHalf)
    index[0] += 1

    print(pairingDict)
    scheduler(firstHalf, pairingDict, index)
    print(pairingDict)
    scheduler(secondHalf, pairingDict, index)
    print(pairingDict)
    return pairingDict


result = scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict, index)
print(result)
```

or you can simply use the length of `pairingDict` plus 1 as the index:

```
import math

coordKeys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

pairingDict = {}

def scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict):
    length = len(coordKeys)
    if length == 1:
        return

    dividerInd = math.ceil(length / 2)
    firstHalf = coordKeys[:dividerInd]
    secondHalf = coordKeys[dividerInd:]

    pairingDict[len(pairingDict) + 1] = (firstHalf, secondHalf)

    print(pairingDict)
    scheduler(firstHalf, pairingDict)
    print(pairingDict)
    scheduler(secondHalf, pairingDict)
    print(pairingDict)
    return pairingDict


result = scheduler(coordKeys, pairingDict)
print(result)
```

Both would output the following in the last line:

```
{1: ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4]), 2: ([0, 1], [2]), 3: ([0], [1]), 4: ([3], [4])}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I was under the impression the in-place assignment (+=) would propagate throughout the whole recursive chain as I put the index += 1 line above the recursive calls to 'scheduler' function in the lower end of the code.